# Distance and Clustering of subset

Tags: classification, distance

So, I have 3 categories, $A$ (6 samples), $B$ (3 samples), and $C$ (7 samples).

I have another data set $X$ (7 samples), for which I want to measure the distance between $A$, $B$, or $C$. $A$, $B$, $C$, and $X$ have close to $20.000$ features.

What is the best way to get the feature subset from $X$ which is closer to $A$, $B$, $C$, or not all of that?

Comment: Habe you tried nearest-neighbor?